# "Memorial" a poem by MacCaig

Tags: meaning, poetry

This poem is *Memorial* by Norman MacCaig. Can you please help me understand what it means and explain how the narrator feels about death and what would be the purpose and audience of this poem?

> Everywhere she dies. Everywhere I go she dies.
>   No sunrise, no city square, no lurking beautiful mountain
>   but has her death in it.
>   The silence of her dying sounds through
>   the carousel of language, it's a web
>   on which laughter stitches itself. How can my hand
>   clasp another's when between them
>   is that thick death, that intolerable distance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for literary interpretation. And for Heaven’s sake, please do others the courtesy of capitalising/spelling things properly and using paragraphs.

Comment: Also avoid titles that can be the opener of your post. Titles should be relevant towards your question and not simply ask for help.

Comment: "hican u" is not proper English.

Comment: It took me a few minutes to work out your original title was: "Hi! Can you please help me? Thanks."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually Norman MacCaig, not "normal maccraigh". I don't think it tells you anything about his attitude to death in general, but rather a specific death. (Most likely his wife, who died about 6 years before he did.)

> Everywhere she dies. Everywhere I go she dies.

Her death haunts him and becomes part of everything he does. It doesn't matter where he goes, all he's reminded of is her death.

> No sunrise, no city square, no lurking beautiful mountain but has her death in it.

Same thing. He can be looking at a sunrise, but can't enjoy what it is because her death is overshadowing its beauty. In a city square surrounded by people and possibly good architecture, "her death" is what he's thinking about and therefore taints his experience. A mountain that most of us might admire for his beauty? He can't, because he's thinking of her death.

> The silence of her dying sounds through the carousel of language, it's a web on which laughter stitches itself.

I think you should be starting to get the idea by now. People are talking, he's thinking about her death. People are laughing, he's thinking about her death.

> How can my hand clasp another's when between them is that thick death, that intolerable distance?

He can't take the hand of a new lover because her death would come between them.

Essentially everywhere he goes and everything he does is defined by her death. And no, it's not a healthy state of mind unless it's an event that happened very, very recently.

Comment: alan k thank you so so much i understand it now thanks very much =)

Answer (score 1):

> Everywhere she dies. Everywhere I go she dies. No sunrise, no city square, no lurking beautiful mountain but has her death in it. The silence of her dying sounds through the carousel of language, it's a web on which laughter stitches itself. How can my hand clasp another's when between them is that thick death, that intolerable distance?
>
> ***THE MEANING***

In essence, the writer seems to be plagued by the omnipresence of the remembrance of a woman's death, possibly a late wife. He cannot seem to escape the reality of her death, since it informs everything he sees, hears, feels, and experiences.

A particularly difficult section of the verse for non-native English speakers might be the section in which "the silence of her dying sounds through the carousel of language, [and] it's a web on which laughter stitches itself."

A couple things:

1. A carousel (or a merry-go-round) turns round and round as the wooden animals on which the children sit go up and down, with happy music playing all the while. A carousel is generally a very pleasant memory in the mind of a child, even years after having ridden on one. Language can often be the messenger of happy things; in this case, however, the silence of the loved one's death overpowers what could potentially be experienced as a pleasant aspect of actual, hearable language (as in words of comfort, for example).
2. The phrase "the silence of her dying sounds" is an oxymoron which could be read in at least two ways: a) the sounds are the actual, hearable sounds the dying person made while in the process of dying--loud gasps for air, perhaps; or b) the silence of her dying (i.e., the whole experience of her death from the grieving person's point of view) sounds, metaphorically, louder than actual spoken words.
3. The phrase "the silence of her dying . . . [is] a web on which laughter stitches itself" is a metaphor which describes aptly how laughter has become a victim of the spider of death. A spider "stitches" the prey which is caught in its web and then kills and consumes it later at its leisure. The grieving person's laughter has become a victim in the grieving process.
4. We normally hold hands with people we love as a way of drawing them closer. This grieving person, however, finds that his grief keeps him at a distance from people, like an invisible barrier which blocks temporarily the normally healing touch of another living person.

> ***HIS FEELINGS***

Obviously, he is in a stage of deep grief, and his grieving is almost more than he can bear. His grief infuses everything he experiences, regardless of how pleasurable those things may have been in his past. So there is certainly grief, but there are also inconsolable sadness, depression, emptiness, and perhaps even despair.

> ***PURPOSE***

I assume the purpose of this writing is for the author to externalize his pain with the most suitable words he can muster, and in so doing perhaps assuage that pain and enable him to deal with it rationally, rather than simply giving in to it and perhaps, as a result, having a breakdown or being tempted to commit suicide to banish the pain.

> ***AUDIENCE***

The audience here could be virtually anyone, or everyone, or no one in particular. It's hard to say which. Each person deals with his or her grief in a unique way. Some folks get into a funk and stay there for a protracted period. Some folks bawl their eyes out. Some folks talk it out in conversation with friends and loved ones. Some people rant at God and blame him for everything that is bad in the world. And then some people compose verse, as this author did.

Regardless of who the audience might be, the author wants *AN* audience to sympathize and empathize with him; again, in an effort to ameliorate the pain he's feeling.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer. I would actually say that it is saying more than that though.

For example, in this part

**The silence of her dying sounds through the carousel of language, it's a web on which laughter stitches itself.**

I think of the meaning to be this:

Carousels go around and around over and over again right?  and it's of language.

I think he is hearing the same conversations/words over and over again but don't help his state of mind at all. Like apologies for his loss, or words of comfort.

The second part:

**It's a web on which laughter stitches itself**

The meaning is:

The carousels are creating a web or again, a circular repeating motion of either laughter which is supposed to help him, or laughter directed at him. I prefer to think of it as the second one because it stitches itself. Meaning the pain of the laughter directed at him clouds or takes over the pain of the loss of the girl.

Other than that I agree with the comment above.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if it does

Comment: ajdollasign21 thanks you very very much and yes it absolutely make sense thanks for you time and help=) and i agree with you to when u talk about the carousel and the second one i trying to following